# CSS background isn't working with nth-child selectors

Tags: html, css, background, css-selectors, background-image

I'm building a portfolio and I'd like to show one work per section in this page:

http://andreawebdesign.com.br/new/portfolio.html

I wanted to do it with this code:

```
.container-portfolio section:nth-child(1){
    background-image: url(../images/seu_roque.jpg);background-position: center;background-size:cover; }
}
.container-portfolio section:nth-child(2){
    background-image: url(../images/seu_roque.jpg);background-position: center;background-size:cover; }
}
.container-portfolio section:nth-child(3){
    background-image: url(../images/seu_roque.jpg);background-position: center;background-size:cover; }
}
.container-portfolio section:nth-child(4){
    background-image: url(../images/seu_roque.jpg);background-position: center;background-size:cover; }
}
.container-portfolio section:nth-child(5){
    background-image: url(../images/seu_roque.jpg);background-position: center;background-size:cover; }
}
.container-portfolio section:nth-child(6){
    background-image: url(../images/seu_roque.jpg);background-position: center;background-size:cover; }
}
```

Of course, the real images will be different, that was just a test. And still, for some reason, the background is shown in the first section, but not in the others. That really confuses me, because I have other codes related to the same sections that are working (just try to mouse over them). I've also tried to call the sections directly by giving each of them a class, but the same error is happening.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The code is commented in style.css.

Comment: Please update your page to demonstrate the problem. The code shown above doesn't appear on your page. Better, create a demo at http://jsfiddle.net or here using a code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have an extra closing brace (`}`) on each line that is breaking the CSS.

```
.container-portfolio section:nth-child(1){
    background-image: url(../images/seu_roque.jpg);background-position: center;background-size:cover; }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was something so silly! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Image path is not right.

> > background-image: url(./images/seu_roque.jpg);

Try this it should work.